# How can I stop the "Countdown to Goodness"?

Tags: windows-10, updates

I have Windows update turned off but I am still getting idiotic and extremely annoying "Countdown to the Goodness" messages every hour. How can I make it stop forever? (short of dropping the laptop off a 400 foot building or installing Linux on it)

Comment: I have Windows Update turned on and I've no idea what you're referring to by "Countdown to the Goodness".

Comment: @grawity Well, in that case it is pretty unlikely you will be able to correctly answer the question.

Comment: Windows isn't compulsory, it's not even necessary - in fact we only have one of them left in the building, in case of user queries. Feel free to choose another operating system & don't blame your hardware.

Comment: @Tetsujin Where did he blame the hardware?

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik - Umm thanks for that(?) What I'm really interested in though is if you know how to answer the question and disable the "Countdown to Goodness" update alerts

Comment: @user33339 - probably in some long-deleted & long-forgotten comment.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of windows are getting very penetrant in forcing Home versions to update to the latest security patches (and the latest MS fancyness too, of course).

Most known tricks have been disabled now by Microsoft, so either you spend a lot of time and effort digging through the newest hacker posts and modding your registry, or you give in.

- for the Home edition, the only useful solution is to simply upgrade every time they offer it (it is nowadays pretty painless).
- for Professional and Enterprise editions, you can shut it up and defer upgrades for several months. Although if you are not a security expert, and live behind a state-of-the-art firewall, this is risky (google 'ransomware'...)
- if you just want to get rid of the pop-up, don't close it, but move it to the very bottom of your screen, so only a single row of pixels are still 'visible', and leave it there.

Comment: If you move it to the corner of the screen, it will simply restart at the time it says it will (10 minutes after the 'Countdown to Goodness' alert appears).  This is the 3rd time this week it has forced a restart. There must be a way to disable this!